# Git: How is the SHA1 value of a tree object generated?

Tags: git, sha

As the title suggest, is the value based on the content of all tree objects(recursively) inside?

Namely, can I regard two tree objects as the exactly same file tree (including all the subdirectories and files) if they have the same hash value?

Comment: I don't know the details of the implementation, but Linus himself has claimed your last statement to both be true and the overall basis of git.

Comment: What do you mean by subtrees - can you give a contrite example to explain your question as it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see some rough details about what is used to calculate the tree SHA [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Tree-Objects).

Further information about the binary format that the tree is stored in can be found [here](http://smalltalkthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/git-tree-objects-how-are-they-stored.html).

The actual SHA that is used is just the SHA of the buffer described in that detailed version.

The key points to take home is that the SHA is dependent on the filenames of all contained objects or trees, their SHAs and their permissions. Change any of those and you change the SHA. If two trees have the same SHAs then all those components must match (excluding the possibility of collisions as they're nigh on impossible).

Comment: excuse me, but it seems not to talk about how the SHA is calculated in detail. What I've found is the sentence: "`This is the SHA-1 hash — a checksum of the content you’re storing plus a header`".

Comment: Added a bit more that details how the tree is stored and how the SHA is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have two tree objects that have the same hash since the object file is named by the hash in the repository. Also, in order for two tree objects to be the same, it would require that state of the commit be identical in both cases right down to the content of all the staged files since the tree object keeps SHA-1 references to the staged files.

This [post](http://gnuromancer.org/2013/01/14/git-guts/) might help clarify this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on [Michael Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085160/1256452), a tree object's hash is computed the same way as any other object's hash: it's H(object-content-including-header), where H is the hashing function (SHA-1 or, now, SHA-256).  The contents-including-header have the form described in the links:

- The type of the object: the literal text "blob", "tree", "commit", or "tag" (followed by a space).  These are in ASCII or UTF-8 (since they consist only of ASCII bytes, it's just a byte-string either way).
- An ASCII representation of the size of the object, in decimal.  For instance, if the remaining data are 16 bytes long, we get ASCII characters `1` and `6`.
- An ASCII NUL (zero byte).
- The object's raw data.

For a *tree* object, the raw data are some number of repeating occurrences of a three-tuple: mode, name, hash.  The mode is an octal number without leading zeros, represented in ASCII.  It is separated from the name by a space (byte value 32 decimal).  The name is generally assumed to be UTF-8 bytes, although there is little or no checking that it's valid UTF-8; it must not contain an ASCII `/` or NUL character.  It is terminated by an ASCII NUL.  The hash is a raw 20 byte hash ID when using SHA-1, or 32 byte hash ID when using SHA-256.

These three-tuples are generated from Git's index, and Git's index is kept in a sorted order.  This means that if you want to generate the *same* tree object data that *Git* would, you must produce the entries in the *same order*.  I have sample Python code that will read a directory and gather up the data that would go into the tree object [here](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py).